# C# Interop Outlook Contacts not iterating through all Items

Tags: c#, interop

I want to delete all Outlook Contacts with a CustomerID. So I thought it would be easy to get all Contacts with Interop and iterate through them and check if they have the CustomerID I want.

So this is what I coded:

```
var app = new Application();

var folderContacts = app
  .ActiveExplorer()
  .Session
  .GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

var searchFolder = folderContacts.Items;

foreach (ContactItem foundContact in searchFolder)
    if (foundContact.CustomerID == myCustomerIdAsString)
        foundContact.Delete();
```

This gets all Contacts, but my problem is, that it do not iterate through all Items. Look at this picture:

[image: My Code after Executing]

You can see, it iterates through about the half of the items. But I don't know why.

Anyone an idea what to do?

Comment: My first guess would be, that it's because of the searchFolder-Items are mutated in the iteration itself (by deleting items). You could test it using an "old fashioned" For-loop that starts at the end and decrements: `for (int i = searchFolder.Count; i > 0; i--)
    if (searchFolder[i].CustomerID == myCustomerIdAsString)
        searchFolder.Remove(i);`

Comment: @Yosh I think you are right. But I left my foreach and add the contacts to a list. After the foreach I do this : `contacts.ForEach(x => x.Delete());` And it works properly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Yosh wrote in his comment, the searchFolder Items are mutated in the iteration itself. Because of that I put the entitis to delete in a collection and delete them after the iteration.
I want to delete all Outlook Contacts with a CustomerID. So I thought it would be easy to get all Contacts with Interop and iterate through them and check if they have the CustomerID I want.

So this is what I coded:

```
var app = new Application();

var contacts = new List<ContactItem>();

var folderContacts = app
  .ActiveExplorer()
  .Session
  .GetDefaultFolder(OlDefaultFolders.olFolderContacts);

var searchFolder = folderContacts.Items;

foreach (ContactItem foundContact in searchFolder)
    if (foundContact.CustomerID == myCustomerIdAsString)
        contacts.Add(foundContact);

contacts.ForEach(x => x.Delete());
```